# Modifiy method called from extended class

Tags: java, extends

I have three classes, and I need to modify first class through the second that is extended :

my first class A :

```
public class A{

private String name;

public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
```

my second class B

```
public abstract class B  {
 public void init() {

   A a = new A();
  a.setHost("foo"); 
 }
}
```

my third class C

```
public class C extends B {
// I want to use the method setName() of the a declared in class B
  b.init.a.setName("bar");//compile error, I tried several syntax I don't know how to do it

}
```

expected output, in my third class :

`a.Getname = "bar"`

Comment: `a` is a local variable which is only available in the scope of the `init` method. You can't access it from outside.

Comment: You literally can't do what you're trying to do.  What you could _possibly_ do is have `a` passed into `init` and built by the caller instead of having it created locally inside `init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

1) Variable b is never declared.
2) Variable a is private to method init, so you can't access it outside the init method.

So the solution should be like:

**Class B:**

```
public abstract class B  {

 protected static A a = new A(); // Protected to make it visible to child class
 public void init() {

  a.setHost("foo"); 
 }
}
```

**Class C:**

```
public class C extends B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    a.setName("bar");
    System.out.println(a.getName());  //Output = bar
  }
}
```

Comment: tried your solution but got a java.lang.NullPointerexception at package.classB.init

Comment: You need to declare the A as static. I have updated the code. It's working now. Sorry for typo. And in my code, there is no call to init.

Comment: well problem is, in my Class B i do `a.setHost("foo") ` then method(a) .. so the method is never called with "bar" but with a.getHost="foo"

Answer (score 0):

you can return a in the init method of B like below.

```
public A init() {

  A a = new A();
  a.setHost("foo"); 
  return a;
 }
```

Then  you can set the value in C like below

```
public class C extends B {
   public setNameinA() {
      B b = new B();
      b.init().setName("bar");
   }
}
```